# why do I keep getting an error when I try to edit the reference line in Tableau box plot?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to follow the following Tableau [tutorial](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_boxplot.htm) on building a box plot.
Trying to follow step 8: editing the reference line, I keep getting the following error:
[Edit reference line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldBmu.png)

note: I didn't know where the dataset they used in the tutorial was, so I kinda searched & used a random dataset I found on Tableau Public. Could that be the reason? knowing that I already copied it to a new worksheet.

Thanks in advance y'all !

I tried redoing it, but the error persists...

Comment: Do not post error/code as image, but as text.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a super generic error and it is very hard to say.

I would suggest to try all of these steps:

1. Try opening and closing Tableau Desktop (sometimes if you left the client opened for too long some authentication problem happens and you can figure out an error like this one);
2. Try to switch the dimension you are using from discrete to continuous or vice-versa;
3. Try to use other dimensions and see if the problem persists. If it persists, probably there is a problem with the steps you are following (and we could not help you as far as we don't know exactly what you are doing).

If the problem persists I would suggest you try to ask on the Tableau forum, not to move people from here to there :-) but because you can easily upload the workbook with the job you have done so far.